# Parallel image detection and camera preview OpenCV Android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I'm using OpenCV to detect an image. Here is my problem: my function `detect_image(mRgba)` needs some time to perform operations and give some results. While function is computing camera preview is frozen because it only shows image when code reaches `return inputFrame.rgba()` I would like to know how to make those operation parallel, function will be computing in a background while camera preview is working with normal speed.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
detect_image(mRgba);
return inputFrame.rgba();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To just get a taste at parallelization, the simple approach would be to just use an AsyncTask to process your images:

[AsyncTask reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

A more friendly introduction can be found here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

while this:

http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=11900176

is a nice all-around introduction to multi-threading on Android.

*If you want to just get started*, a simple algorithm should work like this:

- from within your "onCameraFrame" method check if you have an AsyncThread for processing the image which is already running
- if the answer is "yes", just show mRgba in the preview window and return
- if the answer is "no" start a new AsyncThread and let it run "detectImage" on mRgba, making sure that the results are saved in the onPostExecute method.

With this algorithm, if your system can detect 4 images per second while taking a preview at 60fps (for example), you will be able to get a smooth video with a new result about each 20-30 frames on a single processor device, under the realistic assumption that detect_image is CPU intensive while the camera preview/display are I/O intensive.

```
   Capture:     x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x....
   Processing:  1.......1.......1.......1.....1.......1....
                time ------------------------------------>
```

Starting with HoneyComb, a more refined approach would be to account for the number of cores in your CPU (multicore phones/tablets are becoming increasingly common) and start N AsyncTask in parallel (one for each core), feeding a different preview image to each one (maybe using a thread pool...).

If you separate each thread by a fixed delay (about the duration of detectImage/N ), you should get a constant stream of results with a frequency that should be a multiple of the single threaded version.

```
   Capture:     x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x....
   Processing:  1.2.3.4.1.2.3.4.1.2.3.4.1.2.3.4.1.2.3.4....
                time ------------------------------------>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Think I understand, except for the part about "separate each thread by a fixed delay".  If the cores can process in parallel, why would this help?  I think I'm missing something fundamental about this kind of operation.  How would you separate each thread by a fixed delay anyway?  Once you start a thread it just runs doesn't it, regardless of when it was spawned in relation to other threads?

Comment: the general idea (we are talking about concepts here, as I didn't tested the setup myself) is to get evenly separated frames as output. Feeding the first N frames to your N cores without delaying them as I described would give you the same frame rate (or a slightly better one, for what it's worth), but the images would be processed and displayed in "burst" of N images, with large pauses in between, and the viewer would still perceive the result as very jerky. Hope this helps.

Comment: It does. Thanks.  I was thinking the processing of the N frames should be irrelevant to how smooth things appeared bc they weren't on the main thread and logic on the main thread would be responsible for drawing things in a smooth way, but now it seems clear that all the main thread can do is take things as they come. It can't know how to draw the frames in a way that mitigates uneven timing.

Comment: not just that, but even if the UI thread could present the frames at set intervals, the user wouldn't notice; the frames themselves would stem from a very short interval (like 0.066 for 4 cores if detectimage takes 1 sec), with probably imperceptible differences: playing like 4 almost identical frames in 1/4 of seconds doesn't improve the smoothness much...